# PHP check if there is a repeated part in string

Tags: php, arrays, string, spam

I am trying to stop spam and a lot of it is recurring words, is there any way to check the string to see if there is a recurring phrase inside the string?

```
$string = 'Hello ! Hello ! Hello ! Hello !";
```

Thanks,

Comment: What about using [akismet](http://akismet.com/) instead of rolling your own anti-spam solution? I've written a spam-filter for generic texts once, and it's hard to filter without having false positives. Akismet is ready to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substr_count` is fine when you know what you're looking for. If you don't know what is the spam word, you can use `str_word_count` and `array_count_values`:

```
$string = 'Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Lorem Ipsum';
$words = str_word_count($string, 1);
$count = array_count_values($words);
print_r($count);
```

This will give you this:

```
Array
(
    [Hello] => 4
    [Lorem] => 1
    [Ipsum] => 1
)
```

You can `sort()` this array and get a ranking of the most used words on the string. You should also check for stopwords (like "and", "or", "me" and such).

Comment: If there any way to perform a function if one of those words is used, over say, 10 times, excluding common these words: like a, the, my, he, she, that

Comment: You'll need a list of stopwords in an array, then loop through the `$count` list. I believe there is no PHP function that solves the stopword problem by its own. Perhaps `array_filter` can help you.

Answer (score 1):

A fast Google Search gave me that:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

However there are better anti-spam ideas. Like Captchas. Human spammers are pretty difficult to catch. They'll find a way around your word counter. Maybe you should think about an approach of user-based spam report like Youtube does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try substr_count():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$string = 'hello ! hello ! hello ! hello !';
echo substr_count($string, 'hello');
```

Of course if you want to check whether ANY of the words in your string occur multiple times... then this becomes a lot less efficient. You'd probably have to keep track of a list of 'checked words' and, for each not-yet-checked word in your string check whether it occurs multiple times.

LIke Binarious mentioned, a captcha would be a nicer way to stop spam ;-)

Comment: The thing is, i don't know what the repeated string is. I thought there was a boolean function for it...